# In Jenkins, git fetch is very slow, 11 seconds every time

Tags: git, jenkins, fetch, tortoisegit

In Jenkins, when I have a windows batch script call `git fetch`, it takes 11 seconds every time. This happens even if I have just called the same script and waited 11 seconds to fetch the same repo.

The same thing happens if I use the Git plugin when it updates the code at the start of the script. The fetch step takes 11 seconds every time.

I'm working with a bunch of different slave nodes. Some of them have this problem and some of them don't. But it's 100% consistent for each node. Either it happens every time, or none of the time.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 for both master and slave nodes. I'm using msysgit for the git executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing git 2 increased the fetch speed a lot. It seems to have made the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the Jenkins slave service makes this issue go away for a little while at least. But it can come back later.